# Unable to view all hindi sites on MAC 10.5.5

Tags: macos, unicode

I have created a sample Indian site and tried in Safari on MAC 10.5.5, I am unable to view, Browser shows Boxes instead of valid text.

I tried the same on latest firefox browser but same issue. I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 in browser preferences but it not help.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance,
Laxmilal Menara

Comment: I don't see how this is programming-related, so probably it belongs on superuser.com. Maybe it's just caused by missing fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to encode your font with unicode standards

Answer (score 1):

How's encoded your file ? What charset do you provide in your metas ?

A good method should be to encode all your files in UTF-8, and to provide a nice meta as

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Comment: My site have this, but I'm unable to see wikipedia also.

Comment: Then it's probably a problem of font which is not installed on the system.